# How do I delete a dirset of directories with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, build

I want to delete all directories and subdirectories under a root directory that are contain "tmp" in their names. This should include any .svn files too. My first guess is to use

```
<delete>
    <dirset dir="${root}">
          <include name="**/*tmp*" />
    </dirset>
</delete>
```

This does not seem to work as you can't nest a `dirset` in a `delete` tag.

Is this a correct approach, or should I be doing something else?

- ant version == 1.6.5.
- java version == 1.6.0_04

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's the answer that worked for me:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${root}" defaultexcludes="false">
       <include name="**/*tmp*/**" />
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

I had an added complication I needed to remove `.svn` directories too. With `defaultexcludes`, `.*` files were being excluded, and so the empty directories weren't really empty, and so weren't getting removed.

The attribute `includeemptydirs` (thanks, flicken, XL-Plüschhase) enables the trailing `**` wildcard to match the an empty string.

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${root}">
          <include name="**/*tmp*/*" />
    </fileset>
</delete>
```

---

ThankYou  flicken !

Comment: To delete directories, you'll need to add ncludeemptydirs="true", as outlined below.

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add that the part of the solution that worked for me was appending `/**` to the end of the include path. I tried the following to delete Eclipse .settings directories:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes"**/.settings">
</delete>
```

but it did not work until I changed it to the following:

```
<delete includeemptydirs="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes"**/.settings/**">
</delete>
```

For some reason appending `/**` to the path deletes files in the matching directory, all files in all sub-directories, the sub-directories, and the matching directories. Appending `/*` only deletes files in the matching directory but will not delete the matching directory.